# How can I keep in Google Analytics 2 Utms in paralel when one is changed with another?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have developed an app that retargets customers when browsing a website and I have some problem with UTM tracking and Google Analytics.

For example if a client gets a customer to click on a FB ad and lands on their website they will have a custom FB utm. After browsing the website my app will display a pop-up and when a client clicks on it he receives my custom UTM.

The problem is that clients loose conversion rate data for the original traffic source and I need to figure out a solution.

Help is very much appreciate

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about usage of Google analytics application and is not programing related

Comment: @Andrei Where does your link lead them? Is it an internal site link?

Comment: @DalmTo it is indeed programming related.

Comment: @JBrazier the link has the only purpose of tracking conversion in the admin panel of my app. So it fill look something like this: http://example.com/product/utm-myapp-etc and i want it to keep both my app utm and the one from the original source.

Comment: @Andrei You haven't answered my question. As point out by Kemen below, utm tagging on internal links is not good practice. It will ruin your tracking.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practices track with utm inside your site, if the pop-up is on the same domain, dont do it?

In you example, if the user comes from FB, yes, you need to tack with the utm, but the pop up is on your site... lets check the option?

If the asnwer is yes, try to track the user with a Custom Dimention on a Session Level, that will solve almost all your problems.

If the answer is no, you can only store a single UTM per sessions, that means that there is no option to avoid the overwriting the UTM, even consider the referal exclusion.

More about Custom dimentions:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en